# About LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question asks me to give an LU composition of the matrix below

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 7 \\
3 & 6 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I ended up with the following U =

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The question is right here, I thought I should subtract -1 times row2 from row 3 here. But the answer is the U matrix that I've written above. Why aren't we subtracting -1 row2 from row3?? Shouldn't I make sure there are zeros below every pivot or is there some other sort of a logic behind factoring A into LU?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LU decomposition algorithm for a 3x3 matrix, you execute the following operations on the second and third lines ($L_2$ and $L_3$):

$L_2 \leftarrow L_2 - \frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}L_1$ to make $a_{21} = 0$

$L_3 \leftarrow L_3 - \frac{a_{31}}{a_{11}}L_1$ to make $a_{31} = 0$

and $L_3 \leftarrow L_3 - \frac{a_{32}}{a_{22}}L_2$ to make $a_{32} = 0$

In the second operation $a_{32}$ is already zero along with $a_{31}$, so there is no need to execute the last operation. The U matrix is finished because every element below the main diagonal is zero.

Comment: Ahh I see, so the main point is to make sure every element below the diagonal is zero right? :P

Comment: That's right. Then the L matrix will be composed by the 3 coefficients below the diagonal (the values used to multiply the lines), 1 on every position of the diagonal, and 0 above.